# Intersection of two files in R

Tags: r

I have Two files as like this

```
cat.01 dog.01
cat.03 dog.04
cat.05 dog0.2
```

Another file

```
cat.01
cat.05
```

Then I want to print the common based on the first column

```
cat.01 dog.01
cat.05 dog0.2
```

I tried with intersection but it only prints the first column. I tried with merge also but it is taking too much time to respond

Comment: Yes but it taking too much time to respond

Comment: Can you provide data using `dput` of first few lines for both the files ? `dput(head(df1))`, `dput(head(df2))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `%in%`...

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
dt1 <- fread("cat.01 dog.01
cat.03 dog.04
cat.05 dog0.2", header = FALSE )

dt2 <- fread("cat.01
cat.05", header = FALSE)

#  dt1
#        V1     V2
# 1: cat.01 dog.01
# 2: cat.03 dog.04
# 3: cat.05 dog0.2

#  dt2
#        V1
# 1: cat.01
# 2: cat.05
```

**code**

```
dt1[ V1 %in% dt2$V1, ]
#        V1     V2
# 1: cat.01 dog.01
# 2: cat.05 dog0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You want dplyr's filter function

```
name <- c('cat.01','dog.01','cat.03','dog.04','cat.05','dog.02')
name_2 <- c('cat.01','cat.05')

df1 <- matrix(name, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) %>% as.data.frame()
df2 <- matrix(name_2) %>% as.data.frame()
df3 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(V1 %in% df2$V1)
df3
```

```
      V1     V2
1 cat.01 dog.01
2 cat.05 dog.02
```